# How to keep vertices from snapping to to wrong-side of mesh when retopologizing?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode, snapping

I've got a mesh that I'm retopologizing as a practice-run to get used to the motions, having followed the method described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM&t=1218s) by FlippedNormals.  Using 2.8, and settings are as follows:

[image: Snapping] [image: Modifiers]

Everything is working as-expected, except that when I try to extrude down the length of the arm.

[image: Base]

[image: Extrude]

Everything looks fine until I rotate the viewport and see that...

[image: Eep!]

The vertices on the far-side of the retopology are snapping to points closest to the front, relative to the viewport at the time of extrusion.

Is there a way to keep this from happening, and instead just have them snap to the expected-surface of the mesh?  I'm not adverse to the idea of getting 2.79 and nabbing retopoflow should that indeed be the only/ideal solution, but I would definitely prefer to try and keep everything consolidated to 2.8

Thank you very-much, in advance!

Comment: I guess you must not try to snap the vertices when they are on the other side of the object, maybe turn off transparency if it helps

Answer (score -1):

You did not check "project onto self" in the snapping tab. Try that out and see if it helped.